Add label showing feature closest to centre of map view in QGIS
I am using QGIS 3.4 and have a layer with addresses, I want to add a label in the map view with an expression that will get the feature closest to the center of the map and use that to show the address. I can get the central coordinate with item_variables('Map name')['map_extent_center'] but can not get the feature closest to that coordinate.

With the aggregate function you should be able to get all features that are in the current map extent. Then you need to calculate the distance to the center point for each feature and pick the closest one. Look into arrays and generate series to run these kind of calculations at the layout level. Or maybe you can run it on the feature side and just override the label placement.
